# How to make npm script build correct environment?

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

I am building a react-native project and am switching between staging and production environments with the use of react-native-config library. I have my environments defined in separate .env files (.env.dev, .env.staging, .env.prod), and I have the following npm scripts defined in my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "android-dev": "ENVFILE=.env.dev react-native run-android",
    "android-staging": "ENVFILE=.env.staging react-native run-android",
    "android-prod": "ENVFILE=.env.prod react-native run-android",
    "android-release": "react-native run-android --variant=release",
    "build-android-staging": "export ENVFILE=.env.staging && cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease && cd ..",
    "build-android-prod": "export ENVFILE=.env.prod && cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease && cd .."
  }
```

In my build.gradle I have placed the following

```
project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
  debug: ".env.staging",
  release: ".env.prod",
  anycustombuildlowercase: ".env.staging",
]
```

I think there is a conflict with between the scripts and the build.gradle code, because when I run `npm run build-android-staging` it builds release in production environment. If I remove the code in build.gradle and call an api, I receive `Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
unexpected url: undefinedapi/` error. What do I need to alter to allow for my build scripts to work with the correct environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time of research I finally came across this issue [this issue](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config/issues/175) where somebody laid out exactly how to do this. In build.gradle, I had to add

```
project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
  debug: ".env.staging",
  release: ".env.prod",
  releaseStaging: ".env.staging", <---- THIS LINE
  anycustombuildlowercase: ".env.staging",
]
```

And in same build.gradle file, add

```
releaseStaging {
          minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
          useProguard enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        }
```

under buildTypes. Then in package.json I created this node script

```
"android-release-staging": "react-native run-android --variant=releaseStaging".
```

Now I can finally create a production build using staging.